# Best database type to store data that will be used with a blockchain?

Tags: sql, database, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

For a project, I'm using Hyperledger Composer Fabric to create a blockchain for an integrated healthcare system for integrity and fast access purposes. I don't want to store the actual healthcare records on the blockchain because they'll be large. Instead, I was thinking of storing a hash of the record on the blockchain and storing the records in a database. What kind of database would be best? I've used relational databases and SQL before only. Could this suit? I've seen some people say to store the location of the data on the blockchain too, how would you do this? This is only a small project, so I'm looking for simple solutions rather than some I see which are for real, enterprise systems.

Comment: If you are using Fabric then create a data structure that needs in blockchain rather than storing entire record set with relation to various structure or classes. You can store the unique key of your sql database table in blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

Storing just the hash on the blockchain is fine. Just use the Composer Rest Server functionality to expose a RESTful endpoint to add and read the data. You can call this endpoint from the datalayer of you application.

In terms of the database, If you know SQL use a SQL database. The kind depends on the development environment you are using. I am a Microsoft fan but MSSQL Server costs much more than POSTGres or MySQL. If the database is not big, look at the AWS RDS cloud databases.

You can store the location of the data on the blockchain. Just define an asset in the Composer CTO field and give it a String property with the file location. There are code examples in the Playground for reading and writing to the autogenerated Asset Registry. You will also get a RESTful endpoint to read and write this data.

Answer (score 0):

Storing a hash of the record on chain and the data off chain is a typical solution and a good start. Selecting or creating the data storage architecture is the harder part and the answer depends on the politics and needs of the consortium that will be using your blockchain, how much trust they are willing to put in a centralized entity to maintain the privacy and integrity of the system.

Storing the data in a single SQL db you control effectively turns your solution from a decentralized, low trust solution into a centralized, high trust solution. The same goes for inserting a REST API between clients and the data. This forces clients of your blockchain to trust your company to maintain that API and SQL database and the integrity of the data in it. If that's acceptable to them then you may not need a blockchain at all.

A better solution is to choose a database, file store or Key-Value store that is designed for decentralization and replication such that blockchain clients can host their own database nodes if they don't fully trust some other entity to maintain the network. You might look at ArangoDB, CockroachDB, Couchbase and others.

If your clients are ok with relying on a cloud provider such as AWS to maintain uptime and integrity you may be able to get away with using cloud services to distribute and load balance a data store such as Dynamo, spanning several regions in case one region goes down. This adds a level of trust and centralization that may be acceptable to clients of the blockchain (they now trust Amazon will manage infrastructure and uptime), but it still puts you on the hook for managing and owning access (keys to the AWS account).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to taking an api call with provided provider/patient information that returns an object then taking that information and storing in a constructor that is then hashed and stored on the blockchain?
If so I would recommend going to this link to find more information from EagleSoft (a dental software created by Patterson dental) documentation:
https://pattersonsupport.custhelp.com/euf/assets/Answers/29059/Eaglesoft%20Innovation%20Connection%20Sample%20Application%20Documentation.pdf